# Hypothetical sentence ( present/future)

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

> I wouldn't be a good friend if **I'm not** honest about it and **hide** it.
>
> I wouldn't be a good friend if **I wasn't** honest about it and **hid** it.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wouldn't be X if I **don't** ...
>   I wouldn't be X if I **didn't** ...

Both of these are fine.  It doesn't matter if you use the present tense or the past tense here.  It's just personal preference.

Because I don't know what "it" refers to in your example, I can't say for certain if the sentences are *natural* English.  Let me give you an alternate example:

> I wouldn't be a good friend if I **don't** tell her that her sister **is** a liar.
>   I wouldn't be a good friend if I **didn't** tell her that her sister **was** a liar.

Diving deeper into some of the subtleties of the grammar:  actually, the verbs in the conditional clause are independent of each other, so it's possible to mix them:

> I wouldn't be a good friend if I **didn't** tell her that her sister **is** a liar.

This depends on context. The present tense is more *universal* -- it defines what I believe her to be, both now and in the past.

> John **is** a good person.

The past tense says that someone *used to be* something, but may not necessarily be now.

> John **was** a good person, before the war.

So which I use depends on whether I believe her sister is a liar *all the time*, or just lying in that one particular instance.  In your example, which you choose might depends on whether the speaker is hiding "it" *now*, or hid it *in the past*.

To make this more confusing, English speakers will often use the past tense to match the verb, even though they're talking about a current condition or situation:

> I wouldn't be a good person if I **didn't** stand up for what I **believed** in.

This *doesn't* mean I changed my beliefs.  It just sounds nice because the verb tenses match.  It's exactly the same as:

> I wouldn't be a good person if I **didn't** stand up for what I **believe** in.

Comment: In my example I'm talking about now If I hide it now and don't tell my friends about it  it's like your sentences I wouldn't be a good friend if I don't tell her that her sister is a liar.
I wouldn't be a good friend if I didn't tell her that her sister was a liar. the two has the same meaning right ?

Comment: @con - That follow-on question probably should have been part of your original question. The short answer to more than half of the "Which one is correct?" questions I see on ELL is, _"Both, depending on what you are trying to say."_